# Rcpp compilation error

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to compile the simple [Rcpp example](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.examples.html) from [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) webpage with `inline`:

```
Rcpp::NumericVector orig(vector);                  
Rcpp::NumericVector vec(orig.size());          
std::transform(orig.begin(),orig.end(),vec.begin(),sqrt);

return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("result")=vec,Rcpp::Named("original") =orig);
```

However I get the following error:

```
no matching function for call to 'transform(Rcpp::traits::storage_type<14>::type*, Rcpp::traits::storage_type<14>::type*, Rcpp::traits::storage_type<14>::type*, <unresolved overloaded function type>)
```

I am using Windows XP with Rtools (other examples without STL works!), with R 2.12.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ahh. `sqrt()` is now overloaded in Rcpp sugar so you need to explicitly refer to the symbol from the global C++ namespace that is imported from C.  So try this line instead:

```
std::transform(orig.begin(),orig.end(),vec.begin(),::sqrt);
```

with which it works here:

```
R> require(inline)
R> src <- '
+     Rcpp::NumericVector orig(vector);
+     Rcpp::NumericVector vec(orig.size());
+     std::transform(orig.begin(), orig.end(), vec.begin(), ::sqrt);
+     return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("result") = vec,
+                               Rcpp::Named("original") = orig);
+ '
R> fun <- cxxfunction(signature(vector="numeric"), src, plugin="Rcpp")
R> fun(1:9)
$result
[1] 1.00000 1.41421 1.73205 2.00000 2.23607 2.44949 2.64575 2.82843 3.00000

$original
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

R>
```

Can you send me the URL of the page / example that needs an update?

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.examples.html) you go. And it works, thx!

Comment: Ok, I fixed the html page too by adding the now-required `::` before `sqrt`.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel in sugar `sqrt` is not listed (at least I haven't seen it:)) Is there a list of all the sugar functions?

Comment: But it is defined, see `Rcpp/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/math.h` and as so often, *"use the source, Luke"* is the rule to go by.